# How can I use two information tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, information-schema

I need to get a couple of values from the tables in my SQL Server. I have the following SQL statement but its keeps giving an error how can I fix this?

```
select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS,
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
```

Comment: Please post the errors you get.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Read the answer down

Comment: That is not the point. You need to include the errors so people really **know** what the problem is (instead of guessing with incomplete information), and so it might help future visitors which have the same error.

Comment: You need a join condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use alias names because both tables contains column names(table name and column name).

```
SELECT A.TABLE_NAME,
       A.COLUMN_NAME,
       CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A,
       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE B
```

Comment: Thank you ;) I need to wait 12 minutes to accept your answer

Comment: A and B as table aliases? I'd go with C and KCU here.